# Google Maps Javascript : Drag one finger doesn't work on ipad with ios 9 and older

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, drag, touch-event

I am using Google Maps API to build a website, and using option "greedy" to pan the maps with one finger. But, it doesn't work on an iPad with iOS 9 or older. The others work well.

I also tried to listen to the map event, and only the 'click' event is detected, 'drag' event isn't listened.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  </head>
  <body style="overflow: hidden;margin:0;">  
    <div id="map" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;"></div>
<script>
    var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 10.8527, lng: 106.7476},
        mapTypeControl:true,
        mapTypeControlOptions:{mapTypeIds: "roadmap", style: 2, position: 3},
        scaleControl:true,
        zoom:13,
        draggable: true,
        gestureHandling:"greedy",
        });   
    }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB0QGNZHfTyzSc1piB4n3wuHRP2L4RdLys&callback=initMap">
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One hand? Really?

Comment: I am sorry, I tried to edit you question but really it's a total mess. You use the word hand for finger apparently and the rest isn't much clearer. Please **rewrite your question** so that it can be understood!

Comment: Edited , hope someone help me.

Comment: So the issue is limited to iPad with iOS 9 and later? Because on iPhone with iOS 11 it works just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work on ipad 2,3,4 with ios 7, ios 9 ( and, it doesn't work with maps.google.com , too)